# Using Kafka Producer Node in IBM ACE v11

Tags: apache-kafka, websphere, producer

I am using Kafka Producer node for the first time in IBM ACE v11 toolkit. I am getting an error of TimeoutException: Topic {TopicName} not present in metadata after 60000ms.Can someone tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: Well, does it exist? Are you using the correct security settings for your cluster?

Comment: Yes, it does exist. I added few config files related to Kerberos and now I am getting an error of Failed to construct Kafka producer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the follow parameters are correct:

- topicName
- BootStrap
- *verify firewall condictions to access bootstrap servers